# How do I apply properties to a previous sibling on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anchor

I have two under ordered lists, both with the same links, but with different formatting. One is thumbnails, the other is an actual text list. When the user hovers over the thumbnails, the anchor's CSS properties change. I'd like the same thing to happen when the user hovers over the text list (thus highlighting the appropriate thumbnail from the first list). So:

When the user hovers over the first UL, the respective thumbnail anchor background changes to red. When the user hovers over the second UL, the corresponding thumbnail anchor on the first list again changes to red.

Essentially when the user hovers over client two on the text list, the thumbnail for client two will change to red.

I know this is not possible with CSS, given that the second UL is not the parent of the first. How do I achieve this with jQuery?

HTML:

```
<ul id="client-thumb">
    <li><a href="#client-one">Client one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#client-two">Client two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#client-three">Client three</a></li>    
</ul>

<ul id="client-list">
    <li><a href="#client-one">Client one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#client-two">Client two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#client-three">Client three</a></li>    
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul#client-thumb li {
     display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

ul#client-thumb li a {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

ul#client-thumb li a:hover {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
```

Working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/AKtRe/2/

Thanks.

Comment: Without Javascript, with the current DOM, it is not possible. Also, is it normal that the `href` is the same for the 6?

Comment: Can you clarify a little? You want to the CSS properties of the first list to change when the first OR the second list is hovered over? Or do you want something different? It's unclear at the moment, but what it sounds like your describing is possible with CSS.

Comment: The ids are different right?? Like `client-one`,`client-two`...

Comment: I can IDs that's not problem. @j809

Comment: I accept that I need to use JS, that's okay. The `href` are supposed to be different, I updated my original post clarifying. @Karl-AndréGagnon @TylerH

Comment: use classes to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you want the "hover" properties to be applied to the boxes when the user hovers over the corresponding text.

This can't be completed in plain CSS and HTML as mentioned above, but can definitely be done using jQuery using either the [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) or [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) functions and applying the class when the user hovers over the text.

You can add the following jQuery code (from [@MrCode 's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24617204/3133680) -- see it for a working demo)

```
$('#client-list a').hover(
    function(){
        $('#client-thumb a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').css({ background : 'red', color : 'white' });    
    },
    function(){
        $('#client-thumb a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').removeAttr('style'); 
    }
);
```

This allows you to add the style on mouseenter (the first handler/parameter in the hover function) and remove it on mouseleave (the second handler).

Comment: Yes exactly. I have no idea how to write this in jQuery. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with css since they're not adjacent. You can use this jQuery code :

```
$('a').hover(function(){
    $('[href='+$(this).attr('href')+']').toggleClass('hover')
})
```

That toggle a class hover to the appropriate anchor. Just change your CSS `:hover` to `.hover`.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/AKtRe/5/

Answer (score 1):

The *functionality* you want is actually possible with pure CSS, it just takes *a bit more work*. Below is a nearly identical design to your first one with the added functionality you desire. A JSFiddle link is included at the bottom.

Please note this answer isn't meant to serve as a purely practical approach (since the other answers show that your desired functionality can be achieved with only a few lines of jQuery), but rather as an informative approach; an exercise in CSS positioning.

HTML:

```
<ul id="client-thumb1">
    <li><a href="#client-one">Client one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#client-one">Client one</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="client-thumb2">
    <li><a href="#client-one">Client two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#client-one">Client two</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="client-thumb3">
    <li><a href="#client-one">Client three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#client-one">Client three</a></li> 
</ul>
```

What I've done here is split your two lists into three; instead of having a list for the thumbs and a list for the text links, you now have a single list for each client, and the end result is the same, as you can see from the JSFiddle link below.

Now, I've had to really hack at the CSS to get it to look the same. The bottom line is, the functionality is achievable with pure CSS, *so long as you're willing to do more work to position it*. After all, you never said it couldn't be ugly! (or non-responsive)

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

li:first-child a {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-top: -2px;
}

#client-thumb1 li:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}

#client-thumb2 li:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 130px;
}

#client-thumb3 li:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 250px;
}

#client-thumb1 li:last-of-type a, #client-thumb2 li:last-of-type a, #client-thumb3 li:last-of-type a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 365px;
    line-height: 10px;
}

#client-thumb1 li:last-of-type a {
    top: 10px;
    width: 70px;
}

#client-thumb2 li:last-of-type a {
    top: 30px;
    width: 70px;
}

#client-thumb3 li:last-of-type a {
    top: 50px;
    width: 70px;
}

ul#client-thumb1:hover li:first-child a {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}

ul#client-thumb2:hover li:first-child a {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}

ul#client-thumb3:hover li:first-child a {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
```

To make a long story short, I've essentially just applied `position: absolute` to the `li` elements using `first-child` and `last-of-type` pseudo selectors to differentiate between the thumb links and the text links.

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/AKtRe/17/)**

As a matter of interest, here is a different **[JSFiddle Implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/sLfTs/1/)** by **[Ryan Kinal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/363815/ryan-kinal)** that uses much less code to achieve roughly the same output. It just goes to show you that one's code can always be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give each "client" their own class

So both li's would have class="client-one", class="client-two" etc...

Then in jQuery fyou can select them by classname and change their style

```
var whichever = "one";
$(".client-" + whichever).css({"background": "red", "color": "white"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) find find the related thumb by using an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kMg6u/)

```
$('#client-list a').hover(
    function(){
        $('#client-thumb a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').css({ background : 'red', color : 'white' });    
    },
    function(){
        $('#client-thumb a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').removeAttr('style'); 
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a shot at this too:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AKtRe/10/

```
$("#client-list a").mouseover(function(){
    var r = $(this).parent().index();
    $("#client-thumb li:eq(" + r + ") a").css("background","red").css("color","white");
});

$("#client-list a").mouseout(function(){
    var r = $(this).parent().index();
    $("#client-thumb li:eq(" + r + ") a").css("background","#ccc").css("color","black");
});
```